# Finding the number of solutions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, linear-programming, dynamic-programming

$$x_1+x_2+...+x_p+y_1+y_2+...+y_q \ge X$$ where $$x_1,x_2..x_p, y_1,y_2..y_q$$ are all non-negative integers, $$x_1..x_p\le a$$ 
$$y_1...y_q\le b?$$

The original problem is 
  "You are given $N$ distinct boxes of marbles in total. There are $P$ boxes each containing $A$ number of marbles and remaining $Q$ boxes contains $B$ number of marbles each. Given a number $X$, you have to find total the number of ways in which you can pick at least $X$ marbles from the boxes. Print total number of ways modulo $1000000007$".
or in other words how many solutions are there for the above LPP.
I am completely lost here,any mathematical relations or approaches are welcome.Also guidance in efficiently coding the solution approach is also needed.Thank you!

Comment: Nice try,You know what I mean ;)

Comment: I have a O(n) solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593650/combinatorics-number-of-ways

Comment: Was this question asked in a contest because many people have asked the same question nearly 3 to 4 times.

Comment: @Manthanein He is looking for the code and that soln won't work for this problem.

Comment: @Manthanein Yes, that's why I wrote "Nice Try".The question was asked in a hiring challenge.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Demonking28 The contest is over by now and I aint trying to appropriate others code.I just want to understand the solution.

Comment: @Demonking28I came across the problem yesterday itself,but I waited till the end of contest to post the question.So I didnt try what you meant :)

Comment: @SamKadhanayagan I have a solution to the problem but the contest is still active.

Comment: @Demonking28 Bro the contest was over 40 mins back ..-_- https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/hiring/cogoport-developer-hiring-challenge/

Comment: @SamKadhanayagan There is a possibility that a person starts the contest from 10.59 P.M and for him, the contest will end at 12.59 A.M

Comment: @Demonking28 Oh! Ok then,please do explain the solution after that time.

Comment: @SamKadhanayagan Yes,I will :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: not what the problem was asking. I thought it meant you had to take the whole box.

I am not sure on how to do this with mathematics, but I can help you code the solution.

Some definitions I am going to use:

- box 1 = the type of box that has A marbles
- box 2 = the type of box that has B marbles

---

1. Keep a tally for the Solution. I'll call it $S$ for solution.
2. Start with the least number of box 1's possible while having 0 box 2's

   - This is $min(ceiling(\frac{X}{A}), P)$
3. Keep a running count of how many box 1s you have currently, I'll call it $K$. 
   K = result obtained from step 1
4. Keep a running count of how many box 2s you have currently, I'll call it $L$. L = 0
5. Increase L by one, and decrease K until K is the smallest possible.

   - To satisfy your constraints, K can be it's current value, all the way up to its max, P
   - Add $P-K+1$ to $S$
6. Repeat Step 4 until $L = Q$
7. The answer should be $S$

My Java code here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // input
    int P = 5, A = 7, Q = 9, B = 11, X = 100;

    int AMT1 = 0, AMT2 = 0;
    int S = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < P; i++) {AMT1 += A;if(AMT1 >= X) break;}
    if(AMT1 > P) {
        AMT1 = P;
        sum = AMT1*A;
        while(sum < X) {
            AMT2++;
            sum += B;
        }
    } else sum = AMT1*A;
    while(AMT2 <= Q) {
        System.out.println(AMT1);
        S += P - AMT1 + 1;
        AMT2++;
        sum += B;
        while(sum - A > X) {
            sum -= A;
            AMT1--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(S);
}
```

Comment: The sample case given in the contest problem was P = 2, A = 2, Q = 1, B = 1,X = 3 for which the answer was 9.But your code gave the output 2.The problem meant that you could even choose not to select any marbles from a box.Have you taken this into consideration ?

Comment: Oh. Misunderstanding. I assume now that you are not required to take the whole box, but you can take any number of marbles from the box, right? If so, the problem definitely becomes harder.

Comment: Yes @Gabe The problem is that you can choose to select any number of balls from a particular box ranging from 0 to the total number of balls in the box.Only constraint is that the sum of the chosen balls from all the boxes at the end must be greater than or equal to X.