# Inclusion Exclusion Problem: $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 17$ subject to the restrictions that $x_i \leq 7$, $1 \leq i \leq 3$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many solutions are there to

$x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 17 $ where  $x_{i} \leq  7$  for  $1\leq i \leq 3$

This problem and solution comes from this youtube video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0CYHMqomgI&t=475s

**Solution**

$ x_{i} \leq 7 \rightarrow  $   $  \overline{c_{i}} = x_{i} < 8 \rightarrow $ $ c_{i} = x_{i} \geq 8 $

$N(\overline{c_{1}c_{2}c_{3}}) = N - (Nc_{1}+Nc_{2}+Nc_{3}) + N(c_1c_2) + N(c_1c_3) + N(c_2c_3) - N(c_1c_2c_3)$

I understand the rest of the solution but not this negation part. How did he find out $N(\overline{c_{1}c_{2}c_{3}}) $  ?

Comment: Do you know the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for three sets?  It says that $$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$$  Also, you should specify that we are seeking nonnegative integer solutions.

Comment: You could also try to explore other techniques, like generating functions, examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514510/how-many-solutions-are-there-to-xyz-14-where-x-y-z-are-all-non-negative-in/2514527#2514527) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533874/how-many-possibilities/2537977#2537977)

Comment: Also, are you familiar with [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)?

Comment: Ok thanks is he using the "Inclusion-Exclusion Principle" with other terms?

Comment: can i use the method here shown in the youtube video if i got an equation with x1 + x2 + x3 +x4 +x5?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{7}\sum_{x_{2} = 0}^{7}
\sum_{x_{3} = 0}^{7}\bracks{z^{17}}z^{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}}} =
\bracks{z^{17}}\pars{\sum_{x = 0}^{7}z^{x}}^{3} =
\bracks{z^{17}}\pars{z^{8} - 1 \over z - 1}^{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{17}}\pars{1 - z^{8}}^{3}\pars{1 - z}^{-3} =
\bracks{z^{17}}\pars{1 - 3z^{8} + 3z^{16}}\pars{1 - z}^{-3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{17}}\pars{1 - z}^{-3} - 3\bracks{z^{9}}\pars{1 - z}^{-3} +
3\bracks{z^{1}}\pars{1 - z}^{-3}
\\[5mm] = &\
{-3 \choose 17}\pars{-1}^{17} - 3{-3 \choose 9}\pars{-1}^{9} +
3{-3 \choose 1}\pars{-1}^{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
-{19 \choose 17}\pars{-1}^{17} + 3{11 \choose 9}\pars{-1}^{9}
- 3{3 \choose 1}\pars{-1}^{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\underbrace{19 \choose 17}_{\ds{171}}\ -\ 3\ \underbrace{11 \choose 9}_{\ds{55}} + 3\ \underbrace{3 \choose 1}_{\ds{3}}\ =\
\bbx{15}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks this might be a better general way to solve these types of problems. What is this method called?

Comment: @DanielAndersson I don't think it has any particular name.

Answer (score 0):

There are $15$ triples as the following

$$(3,7,7),(4,6,7),(4,7,6),(5,5,7),(5,6,6),(5,7,5),(6,4,7),(6,5,6),(6,6,5),(6,7,4),(7,3,7),(7,4,6),(7,5,5),(7,6,4),(7,7,3)$$

It is interesting that this number is $1+2+3+4+5$ as we count possible answers for $x_1$ from $3$  to $7$.

Answer (score 0):

We use [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

One of DeMorgan's Laws states that the complement of the union of a collection of sets is the intersection of their complements.
$$\overline{\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i} = \bigcap_{i \in I} \overline{A_i}$$
where $I$ is some index set.  For three sets, we get
$$\overline{A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3} = \overline{A_1} \cap \overline{A_2} \cap \overline{A_3}$$
Hence, 
$$|\overline{A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3}| = |\overline{A_1} \cap \overline{A_2} \cap \overline{A_3}|$$
If $U$ is the universal set, then 
$$|\overline{A_1} \cap \overline{A_2} \cap \overline{A_3}| = |\overline{A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3}| = |U| - |A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3|$$
By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle,
$$|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3| = |A_1| + |A_2| + |A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_3| - |A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
|\overline{A_1} \cap \overline{A_2} \cap \overline{A_3}| & = |U| - (|A_1| + |A_2| + |A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_3| - |A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|)\\
& = |U| - |A_1| - |A_2| - |A_3| + |A_1 \cap A_2| + |A_1 \cap A_3| + |A_2 \cap A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|
\end{align*}
With that in mind, you should have written
$$N(\overline{c_1}~\overline{c_2}~\overline{c_3}) = N - N(c_1) - N_(c_2) - N(c_3) + N(c_1c_2) + N(c_1c_3) + N(c_2c_3) - N(c_1c_2c_3)$$
where we make the following substitutions:

- $N$ for $|U|$
- $N(c_i)$ for $|A_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 3$
- $N(c_ic_j)$ for $|A_i \cap A_j|$, $1 \leq i, j \leq 3$
- $N(c_1c_2c_3)$ for $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|$
- $N(\overline{c_1}~\overline{c_2}~\overline{c_3})$ for $|\overline{A_1} \cap \overline{A_2} \cap \overline{A_3}|$